# Visualization of path-oriented images

Tags: qgis, visualisation

I have path-oriented satellite images, the georeferenced points are written to a header (geotif). When I open them in QGIS each pixel is rotated to the top (North), they are not path-oriented anymore, therefore the visualization is incorrect. I am seeking for open-source software where it is possible to visualize my images correctly so the pixels won't be rotated and will be oriented by some angle? Or how can I do it in QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

The Vertical Photo Place plugin will use the EXIF latitude and longitude information from your images, and the EXIF azimuth values, to place images and rotate them.  The images will not be georeferenced only centered on the location coordinates and rotated accordingly.  [See here](https://verticalphotoplacer.github.io/VerticalPhotoPlacer/) for more information on installing and using this plugin.